# should javascript in a separate .jv extensions have a html doctype because the validator warns me and I'm really confused

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, font-awesome

javascript can't run on my web page,

```
<script>
      // Activate Bootstrap tooltip
      $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
      })

      // Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing
      $('a.nav-link').on('click', function(event) {
        if (this.hash !== '') {
          event.preventDefault();
          var hash = this.hash;<kbd>your text</kbd>
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
          }, 800, function(){
            window.location.hash = hash;
          });
        }
      });
       // Initialize Font Awesome
      FontAwesome.init();
</script>
```

I have tried everything possible, I need a responsive collapse design for smaller screen preset.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If your JavaScript is in a separate `.js` file, you shouldn't have any HTML at all: no `DOCTYPE`, no `<script>` tags, just the JavaScript by itself. For example:

```js
// Activate Bootstrap tooltip
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})

// Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing
$('a.nav-link').on('click', function(event) {
  if (this.hash !== '') {
    event.preventDefault();
    var hash = this.hash;<kbd>your text</kbd>
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 800, function(){
      window.location.hash = hash;
    });
  }
});
// Initialize Font Awesome
FontAwesome.init();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Web Page</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My Web Page</h1>
<!-- HTML goes here. -->

</body>
</html>
```

It looks like you're using jQuery, so you will want to reference that from your HTML file.

If your JavaScript is an HTML file, you can include it like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Web Page</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // Activate Bootstrap tooltip
  $(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
  })

  // Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing
  $('a.nav-link').on('click', function(event) {
    if (this.hash !== '') {
      event.preventDefault();
      var hash = this.hash;<kbd>your text</kbd>
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    }
  });
   // Initialize Font Awesome
  FontAwesome.init();
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My Web Page</h1>

<!-- HTML goes here. -->

</body>
</html>
```